# How to reference GET data in a POST request?

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am writing a POST request where a user tags a picture, therefore an instance of the Tagging table should be created. The picture is sent to the user through the GET request. How to I access for example the resource object that was sent through the GET request in the POST request so that I assign a Tag to a specific resource?

This is what I have tried so far:

**views.py**

```
        if not isinstance(request.user, CustomUser):
            current_user_id = 1
        else:
            current_user_id = request.user.pk

        random_resource = request.GET.data.get('resource')

        tag = request.data.get('tag')

        created = datetime.now()
        
        language = request.data.get('language')
```

Comment: Have you tried just `request.GET['resource']` ?

Comment: @Sharpek I have now, I am getting a MultiValueDictKeyError for the game round however - which I am creating in the get request. No more error for the resource though so Thank you!